# Determining if FileStore is HDD/external drive/other source

Tags: java, nio

How do I determine whether a `FileStore` object (e.g. from iterating over `getFileStores()`) representing C: D: E:, etc, is a fixed disk, external drive, or other storage type ? I want to get the usable space on the user's PC, and iterating over drives and adding bytes together is unsuitable since it shouldn't include other storage types beside the main hard drives. Is there a way to distinguish between these?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this is going to be heavily OS dependent and not exposed directly via java.

Comment: Well i woud go with JNI solution if really needed.Hopefully someone knows a way ,.